# iOS: add a topright corner box, at press on add-button

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

Im new to Xcode and are trying to make a menu, where I have the add button in the right top corner, i have that done, my question is now, how can i add a box (where i add 2 buttons) that will be showed under the Add button (+) when i press it ?

Have tried to google "dropdown menu" and so on but i dont get any result.

So what i want to do is.

1. have a add button in the right top corner in the navigation bar. - DONE
2. When pressing the ADD button a box is showed under the button. - Can't find info about that.
3. So i can add 2 other menu button in that box "Add date" "Add member". - I know how to do that.

.....UPDATE.....
what I want to do is to add somehing so when I press "add" then a box is showed like this in the corner.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so it sounds like you're reasonably new to iOS development. In iOS, the convention is to use a Modal View Controller. These are temporary views that appear overtop of other views. This view can house your form and then you can collect the data from that form as you see fit.

I recommend starting here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html

Good luck! :D

Comment: ahh after some search i think im looking for an action sheet function.

Comment: Your screenshot looks more like a UIPopoverViewController

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html